# Summer '14 Salesforce MVP nominations are open

Tags: discussion

Rather an announcement/reminder than a question. [Salesforce MVP](http://www.salesforce.com/mvp/) nominations are open for the summer release. [(Re-)nominate](http://www.salesforce.com/mvp/nominations.jsp) those who you think are exceptionally contributing to the community we have here on SFSE, and the overall salesforce community!

Comment: So, have you nominated me yet? :)

Comment: @Bachovski yes I have!

Comment: If any wants to be gracious and nominate others, check out the [participiation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/213/alltime/salesforce) to see whose been active. Or just look at your questions and pick out someone whose been extra helpful to you!